# Dependency Injection vs Singleton when using RXJS Subjects

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, singleton

When I am faced with the problem of communication between directly unrelated components, I usually create a service and instantiate RxJS's Subjects in the constructor of that service.

Why not just creating a class and declaring a Singleton in it, and use that whenever I need to access behaviour subjects in components? Which is better performance wise?

Thanks for clearing that out to me.

This is a sample code for Singleton pattern:

```
export class SomeData {

    public subject:Subject = new Subject<string>();
    private static _instance:SomeData;
    public static Singleton() {
        return Some._instance || (SomeData._instance = new this());
    }

    constructor(){...}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do this. But why would you? Angular provides singleton services out of the box. If you let the Angular handle the dependency injection for you, you can achieve the same result, in 3 lines of code.

```
export class SomeData {
  public subject: Subject = new Subject<string>();
}
```